# problem with encoding.utf8.getbytes in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on C#, trying below code

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[str.Length];
buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

In str I've got lengthy data but I've got problem in getting complete encoded bytes.
Please tell me what's going wrong and how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Nothing is probably "goin wrong" here. I believe you will have to clearify your question. What is it that you believe is wrong and what did you expect.

Comment: thanks for reply...
I got complete encoded when i cal for the first time...but when it is called for the second time getting problem...Is ther any restriction on length of the "str" used to get bytes...bcoz str i am using contain lengthy string data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper use is:

```
 byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

Answer (score 6):

Why are you creating a new byte array and then ignoring it? The value of `buffer` before the call to `GetBytes` is being replaced with a reference to a new byte array returned by GetBytes.

However, you shouldn't expect the UTF-8 encoded version of a string to be the same length in bytes as the original string's length in characters, unless it's all ASCII. Any character over U+007F takes up at least 2 bytes.

What's the bigger picture here? What are you trying to achieve, and why does the length of the byte array matter to you?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not make any assumptions about length/size/count when working with encoding, bytes and chars/strings.  Let the Encoding objects do their work and then query the resulting objects for that info.

Having said that, I don't believe there is an inherent length restriction for the encoding classes.  I have several production apps doing the same work in the opposite direction (bytes encoded to chars) which are processing byte arrays in the 10s of megabytes.